# Allow a role to edit a specific taxonomy list of terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

We have a blog that needs to be categorized by topics. I want to allow a blog administrator to add/edit/delete blog topics that are listed in a taxonomy vocabulary. But I don't want to give him add/edit/delete access to other taxonomy lists. Is there a permission that I am missing? Is there a D7 module that handles this? Or can someone point me in the right direction for writing my old module?

Answer (score 2):

[Taxonomy Access Control](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) provides this functionality.  [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) does as well, though it is slightly more complex and from my limited experience performs better when only a single term is used per node to control access.  Workbench (access + moderation) includes a nice set of tools for content moderation and workflow not found in Taxonomy Access Control. Both are worth a look before you decide for your use case.